# Migration to remote installation

Tags: installation, server, virtualbox

I am having difficulty finding a good tutorial on what I am looking to accomplish.

I have in the past few weeks setup a home server (Ubuntu 13.04) with various packages that I now want to have hosted on a VPS.  The time it took to get everything functional was quite substantial (I am extremely new to Ubuntu/Linux).

However the install is a guest OS install on Oracle's VirtualBox.

Most VPS's are not willing to assist me in this issue and instead it seems I will be forced to install one of their default Ubuntu installs (usually 12.04)

So... Let's assume I am forced to install a fresh copy of Ubuntu 12.04 on a VPS... How do I go about migrating my data / programs / configs.... everything from my home installation to the new VPS host... is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is very possible, and there are several paths you can take.  Even though your original machine is a virtual one already, you'll find that guides provided for physical-to-virtual conversions are very helpful - for instance, [this one](https://library.linode.com/migration/migrate-server-to-linode) from Linode.  Other VPS hosts will likely provide at least one way to boot from a separate disk.

If you'd like to be more efficient with your local bandwidth, you can [transfer a list](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=261366) of your installed packages, and have the remote host install them before sending your configuration files, presumably in `/etc` and/or your `/home` or `/root` directories.  You can send files to your remote server using [SFTP](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/TransferFiles), if it's running an SSH server daemon.  SFTP is encrypted over the wire, and  supported by various file managers like [Nautilus](http://linux.about.com/od/ubuntu_doc/a/ubudg10t9.htm) and Thunar.

Note: RSync will also use SSH/SFTP as its transfer protocol, so anything transferred by it will be encrypted as well.  Even if you don't use RSync, it's still a good idea to stop each service before copying its configuration file to the remote server.